# Get attribute from ServletContext on JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, el

How can I find my attribute from ServletContext object on JSP page?

I set it before in:

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServletContextListener.class);

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    logger.info("Init gameEngine in listener");
    Engine engine = Engine.getInstance();
    event.getServletContext().setAttribute("engine", engine);
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {

}}
```

and now want to get on JSP page. 
Maybe it possible to do with `${pageContext.servletContext.attributeNames}`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

using jstl you can directly get application object in jsp

```
${applicationScope['attributeNames']}
```

by using this expression you can get your application level object directly in jsp

**OR**

using scriptlet also can get application object in jsp and
if you are running on web_app version 3.0 and has Servlet 3.0 API you can directly get ServletContext object form HttpServletRequest as shown in below example:

```
<%

     ServletContext sc = request.getServletContext();
     sc.getAttribute("attributeName");

%>
```

but you have to cast your  application object when you use scriptlet to get application object so
`JSTL` is much better to use then scriptlet code

[Read more:](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-get-servletcontext-in-servlet.html#ixzz3EhFCnjpf)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I used ${applicationScope.engine.rooms} and it works for me!)

Comment: there is no method of request.getServletContext(); why

Comment: Use `request.getSession().getServletContext()` instead.

Comment: @shareef This is because you were trying this on Servlet API <3.0 - but the method `getServletContext()` was only added to `HttpServletRequest` in Servlet API 3.0.